# SELECT from joined tables all rows matching pairs

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables joined in a 1-to-many relationship, by Person.ID.

```
Person table:
ID  Name
--  ----
1   Alice
2   Bob
```

```
Color table:
PersonID  Color
--------  -----
   1      Red
   1      Blue
   2      Green
```

So this is effectively just

```
ID  Person name  Colors
--  -----------  ---------
1   Alice        Red, Blue
2   Bob          Green
```

I want to be able to find all rows in `Person` that match any in a **List** of `(name, color)` pairs. A row matches a particular pair if person's name matches `name`, and their colors contains `color`.

For example, I might want to find:

`find( [ (Alice, Red), (Bob, Green), (Cindy, Brown) ]`
which should return:  [(1,Alice), (2,Bob)]

What is the SQL for this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use query like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN Color c on p.id = c.id
WHERE (p.Name,c.Color) IN ( ('Alice', 'Red'), ('Bob', 'Green'), ('Cindy', 'Brown'));
```

**sample**

```
    mysql> SELECT * FROM Person;
    +----+-------+
    | id | Name  |
    +----+-------+
    |  1 | Alice |
    |  2 | Bob   |
    +----+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    
    mysql> SELECT * FROM Color;
    +----+-------+
    | id | Color |
    +----+-------+
    |  1 | Red   |
    |  1 | Blue  |
    |  2 | Green |
    +----+-------+
    3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
    
mysql> SELECT p.*
    -> FROM Person p
    -> LEFT JOIN Color c on p.id = c.id
    -> WHERE (p.Name,c.Color) IN ( ('Alice', 'Red'), ('Bob', 'Green'), ('Cindy', 'Brown'));
+----+-------+
| id | Name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Alice |
|  2 | Bob   |
+----+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't trying to generate the given table, but to find the actual rows that match a list of given pairs. For example, I want to find all rows matching [ (Alice, Red), (Bob, Green), (Cindy, Brown) ] which should return: [(1,Alice), (2,Bob)]

Comment: @zzazzles - I have change my answer. pls test it again